# Expected ')' but can't find where it should go

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode is telling me that I'm missing a ')' but I can't tell where it should go; it makes no sense to me. Have commented out the error message.

Can you look at the code and tell me where it's wrong?

Thank you.

CalculatorViewController.m

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;

@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController
@synthesize display;
@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{

    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
    self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    if (self userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {    // Expected ')'
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    } else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You are actually missing a . - `self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber`

Comment: After an interface name don't belong `()`, I thought?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you're missing brackets. Xcode just assumed you didn't want them since you didn't have an open bracket, so you got the error that you didn't close your parentheses.

```
if([self userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber]) {
   ^                                       ^
```